# ADODB.Recordset AbsolutePage not working with Oracle Database (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, com, ado

I have the following code:

```vb
Dim PageNum AS Integer = 1
Dim ThePageSize As Integer = 30
Dim RowCT As Integer = 0

Dim SqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM TheTable"
Dim TCConStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TCConStr").ConnectionString

Dim Objrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Objrs.Open(SqlStr, TCConStr, 3, 3)

If Not Objrs.EOF Then
  Objrs.MoveFirst()
  Objrs.PageSize = ThePageSize
  Dim TotalPages As Integer = Objrs.PageCount
  Objrs.AbsolutePage = PageNum
End If

While Not Objrs.EOF And RowCT < Objrs.PageSize
  RowCT = RowCT + 1

  'Do Stuff

  Objrs.MoveNext()
End While
Objrs.Close()
Objrs = Nothing
```

When I try to run it I get:
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Current Recordset does not support bookmarks. This may be a limitation of the provider or of the selected cursortype."
The error page points to "Objrs.AbsolutePage = PageNum"

Any ideas of if I have done anything wrong here, or what I can do to get around it? It would kind of really stink to show 500 records on one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My somewhat naïve guess, given that I know very little about ADODB, is that the Oracle provider for ADODB doesn't support paging.  The [documentation for the `AbsolutePage` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680994%28VS.85%29.aspx) does indeed suggest this:

> The provider must support the appropriate functionality for this property to be available.

So, instead of doing the paging in your ADO and VB.NET, you could do the paging in your Oracle query.

The typical way of doing paging with Oracle is to use a query like the following.  This returns the 31st to the 40th rows of the table `some_table`, which would be for the 4th page of 10-row pages:

```
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM (SELECT a, b, c, ROWNUM as num
          FROM some_table
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 40)
 WHERE num > 30
```

The two numbers in this query should be `PageNum * ThePageSize` and `(PageNum - 1) * ThePageSize` in that order.

Note that if the query you're attempting to page has an `ORDER BY` clause or a `GROUP BY` clause, you'll need to move that into another subquery.  For example, if we needed to sort by column `b` and then page the results, we'd use something like:

```
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM (SELECT a, b, c, ROWNUM as num
          FROM (SELECT a, b, c 
                  FROM some_table
                 ORDER BY b)
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 40)
 WHERE num > 30
```